# Nginx as mail reverse proxy to deal with different TLS/SSL certs for different domains

Tags: nginx, reverse-proxy

I have several mail servers which host different domains (e.g. `domain1.com` is served by `mail.domain1.com`, while `domain2.com` is served by `mail.domain2.com`). I try to set up a single point to access these domains' mails so I set up a VM with Nginx server as mail reverse proxy.

Each of the domains uses different TLS certificate so I decided to set up different `server` blocks with different `server_name` and `ssl_certificate` specified (just like I used to do with http `server`'s), like this:

```
mail {
  ...
  server {
    listen              25;
    protocol            smtp;
    server_name         mail.domain1.com;
    ssl_certificate     ...;
    ssl_certificate_key ...;
    starttls            on;
    proxy               on;
    xclient             off;
  }

  server {
    listen              25;
    protocol            smtp;
    server_name         mail.domain2.com;
    ssl_certificate     ...;
    ssl_certificate_key ...;
    starttls            on;
    proxy               on;
    xclient             off;
  }
}
```

but this suddenly won't work, nginx can't run saying "nginx: [emerg] duplicate "0.0.0.0:25" address and port pair in nginx.conf"

I expect `server` blocks will be checked for exact `server_name` and this very block will be used to set up TLS/SSL connection, but I was wrong with that. At the same time, I can't join two domain certs into a single file and use it on a single (joined) server block.

So to say, above is only an example, I used to host many more mail domains, so this problem is huge for me. I can surely proxy IMAP/SMTP with Dovecot's proxy feature while proxy SMTP with some other software (which one?) but Nginx looked like a good universal approach.

Please advice, **if I can archive my goals with Nginx**, or how can I do that without many bits of different software?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: have you take a look on the [manual](https://docs.nginx.com/nginx/admin-guide/mail-proxy/mail-proxy/) IMHO i think postfix with transport maps might be a more suffient place.

Answer (score -1):

install haproxy

```
cat domain1.com.crt domain1.com.key > /etc/haproxy/ssl/domain1.com.pem
cat domain2.com.crt domain2.com.key > /etc/haproxy/ssl/domain2.com.pem
```

cat /etc/haproxy/haproxy.cfg

```
...
listen main-smtp
  mode tcp
  bind :465 ssl crt /etc/haproxy/ssl/
  server s1 127.0.0.1:725 send-proxy
...
```

cat /etc/nginx/nginx.conf

```
mail{
  ...
  server {
    listen 725 proxy_protocol;
    protocol smtp;
    timeout 12000s;
  }
  ...
}
```